# How to control babel-cli output directory

Tags: babeljs

Transpiling js files with babel is easy:

```
$ babel ./src/js --out-dir ./src/js/lib
```

BUT! This results in the following structure:

```
src/
  js/
    foo/
      bar.js
    lib/
      src/
        js/
          foo/
            bar.js
          my-file.js
    my-file.js
```

I require the structure to be like this:

```
src/
  js/
    foo/
      bar.js
    lib/
      foo/
        bar.js
      my-file.js
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I just tried it in my own project and it works as you would expect. Not sure why you are getting the result you described. Maybe try upgrading your babel CLI ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried it many times in my project and I got the desired (correct) result.

Check if you have the latest version of babel/cli installed on your machine.

[Install @babel/core @babel/cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli)